# How do I catch the special fish?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Just recently, I tried to catch the Liege of the Lake for quite some time with no success. Hidden fish don't seem to show up on the fish radar, and I had a few times where I filled the encounter bar entirely only for the hidden fish to leave and hide itself in another part of the fishing spot. This made me wonder: are there some special techniques for finding these fish, let alone catching them?

Answer (score 3):

Sooo...I just caught it finally last night...it is in the Vesperpoo, andl you will need to first get plenty of Dragon's Beard fishing line, the reel and rod from the shop next to that spot (which are like 18000 gil combined), and a green lure which I'll be honest I don't remember the name of and I'm nowhere near my game at the moment, sorry...but you may also want to be at level 7 skill level for fishing as well, since you get linger lasting line.

The key is you need to camp at the haven near that, and when you do there will be a cut scene where Gladio will ask you in the middle of the night like a weirdo if you wanna wake up at the ass crack of dawn to catch that legendary fish...it then becomes a tour, and i believe you will need to also clear the entire vesperpool before it will engage you...take note, it doesn't appear on the HUD, and you will simply have to keep casting til it takes interest in your lure, and then entice it to bite...

After that, once you've got him hooked, you really really REALLY need to be patient...it took me about 4 tries, and I had been fishing for almost 3 hrs to get my skill up, so I was kind of in a groove by that point...his stamina is off the charts and you can only reel when he stops struggling, so you'll need to pay special attention to line tension and also catch the jumps to, if you know what I mean...his "attack" will deplete your line very quickly if you don't just go with the flow and take your time...get ready for 20 minutes of battle fishing, and good luck!

Ps-I tried to upload the photo I took so you could see what your catch would be but it wasn't working...it's gratifying if you like a challenge though

Answer (score 0):

The dreaded lake leige. My advice is get the best rod/reel that you can. Best line too. This one is extra hard because it's almost always vibrating. Never hold the reel button down. I slowly tap it because I know it's going to fight/turn as soon as I do. Patience is key. Wait for the fish to jump and use the direction. It doesn't look like much but every single time you hook it it comes in a little closer.